# VS 2013 with Xamarin 4 crashes at a breakbpoint

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, breakpoints

I have an issue with Xamarin v4 just days after I updated my machine last week. In fact, when I try to set a breakpoint for debugging, Visual Studio 2013 crashes at the breakpoint.

Here is Windows Event log:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

And here is my Visual Studio 2013 info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51209

Installed Version: Professional

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013 06177-004-0447006-02717
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013 06177-004-0447006-02717
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013 06177-004-0447006-02717
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013 06177-004-0447006-02717
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013 06177-004-0447006-02717
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013 06177-004-0447006-02717
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker 06177-004-0447006-02717
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package 1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 12.4.51016.0
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Support for creating and opening ASP.NET web projects
Browser Link: A communication channel between Visual Studio and browsers
Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
Server Explorer extensions for Microsoft Azure Websites
Web publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting providers, on-premises servers, or Microsoft Azure

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2 4.1.21001.0

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013 5.2.21010.0

Common Azure Tools 1.3
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools 1.3
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager 2.8.50926.663
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit 

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU 12.0.30626
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU

PowerShell Tools 1.3
Provides file classification services using PowerShell

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer 1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools 12.0.41012.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Integration 1.0
This package integrates the tools for the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK into the menus and controls of Visual Studio.

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

Xamarin 4.0.0.1712 (cdc0365)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android 6.0.0.35 (d300845)
Visual Studio plugin to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS 9.2.1.55 (edf4e56)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.
```

I tried to re-install Xamarin and Android SDK but the same issue is appearing all the time.

I would be grateful if you have an idea how to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. I removed the unreached Macbook from Xamarin Mac agent list in VS 2013. I found Xamarin is very fragible!